# Ember and internationalization: request for best practices and implementation approach

Tags: internationalization, ember.js, single-page-application

I am working on a single page app that requires internationalization features (translation of all static strings into the user's language and setting date and currency formats).

I am using Ember.js, thus most of the static strings are in html bocks (in templates or views) or are in typical Javascript messages such as "Are you sure you want to delete the ..." (part of controller files).

I am looking for best practices and experiences on how to abstract all these strings and other locale specific bits out of the application.

I see mainly a problem with the fact that the user language is only determined after logging-in.  But at that moment, the complete application is already loaded (in English) and thus "redirecting" to another language is not really possible (unless you load all strings of all possible languages at application start - but this would require too much data to be loaded at start).

Any feedback is wellcome !

**-- UPDATE --**

I found in the meantime the ember-i18n library which I can use for the translation of strings (https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n).

My main question however remains: how can you load dynamically translation.js files corresponding to a selected language or corresponding to the user's langauge after login ?

And is there a way to store the selected language so that at next application start, the application uses the correct language (thus load correct translations file before rendering UI).

Hope somebody can help.

Marc

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065266/ember-dynamic-switch-to-choosen-language-using-i18n-library for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the language settings in a cookie, but that is not a 100% approach. Or just load the translation json with an ajax call as soon as you know the language.

Comment: Thx. I also thought about loading the translations file with an ajax call, but problem is then how to update all the templates that are already rendered during application load.  In the templates I use for example {{t application.statusbar.title}} and all these should be replaced by the new language value ...

Comment: Extra note: I want to prevent that each string must be value bound since this will give serious performance issues (see various questions in stackoverflow).

Comment: What if you just reload the whole page with the right language settings?

Comment: Reloading the whole page mains reloading the whole application, including all JS, templates, views, data, etc.  It is a solution, but rather "drastic" - I prefer to reload only the strings and the templates in which they are used.  I have in the meantime posted a working example at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065266/ember-dynamic-switch-to-choosen-language-using-i18n-library